# Change mouse pointer on component border

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to change the mouse pointer as it moves over the outer borders of a component. Sort of the same way it changes when moved over the borders of a resizable form. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls have events like

[MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter.aspx)
[MouseLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave.aspx)
[MouseHover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover.aspx)

and so on. Use one of them